# T-SQL Need to replace passed in value to escape single quotes

Tags: sql-server, string, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which values are passed in from the use. Sometimes the user passes in values that have single quotes. Ex: test's
   -NOTE: I know that to escape the single quotes I need to double it... Test''s

In my stored procedure i'm executing another stored procedure that is checking for duplicates before I insert or delete a record. To check for duplicates I'm passing the value as a declared variable called @valid_value. I am trying to create a statement that would escape the single quotes if the value passed has a single quote in it.

```
--Original
@column_name varchar(40),
@valid_value varchar(60),
@site_entity varchar(30),
@site_entity_type varchar(1),
@site_id varchar(10),
@message varchar(200) OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @site_specific varchar(1)
DECLARE @column_name_ref_integrity_ck varchar(60)
DECLARE @ref_integrity_ok INT
SELECT @site_specific=
(SELECT site_specific
 FROM table_name
WHERE column_name=@column_name)
SELECT @column_name_ref_integrity_ck=@column_name+'_ref_integrity_ck'
EXEC @ref_integrity_ok = @column_name_ref_integrity_ck @valid_value, @site_entity, @site_entity_type, @site_specific, @site_id, @message OUTPUT
RETURN @ref_integrity_ok




--Here is what im try to make work.
SELECT @valid_value
CASE
    WHEN @valid_value like '%''%' THEN REPLACE(@valid_value, '''','''''')
```

I'm thinking that I select the valid value place it in a case to see if the valid_value contains a single quote, then I can replace the valid_value single quote with more quotes for escaping. But this didnt work im having problems making the syntax for this work correctly.

Here is what I have.

```
@column_name varchar(40),
@valid_value varchar(60),
@site_entity varchar(30),
@site_entity_type varchar(1),
@site_id varchar(10),
@message varchar(200) OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @site_specific varchar(1)
DECLARE @column_name_ref_integrity_ck varchar(60)
DECLARE @ref_integrity_ok INT

SELECT @valid_value
    (CASE
        WHEN @valid_value like '%''%' THEN REPLACE(@valid_value, '''',''''''))

SELECT @site_specific=
(SELECT site_specific
 FROM table_name
WHERE column_name=@column_name)
SELECT @column_name_ref_integrity_ck=@column_name+'_ref_integrity_ck'
EXEC @ref_integrity_ok = @column_name_ref_integrity_ck @valid_value, @site_entity, @site_entity_type, @site_specific, @site_id, @message OUTPUT
RETURN @ref_integrity_ok
```

Comment: This is a classic XY problem. What you need to be doing is using properly parameterized dynamic sql instead of trying to replace single quotes with double quotes. To parameterize your dynamic sql you will need to use sp_executesql instead of exec.

Comment: okay, so I need to replace the 'EXEC' with 'sp_executesql '. I'm not sure what else is needed to parameterize the dynamic sql.

Comment: Here is the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql